# What is the lens on top of the 105mm lens?

Tags: lens

[image]

Does anyone know what's on top of the  AF MICRO 105mm lens?[image]

The picture is quoted from a image system set up, trying to figure out what's each part of them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is an AF Micro-Nikkor 105mm f/2.8D lens. When focusing closely the front element extends out the end of the lens.

[image]

Here are two side-by-side. Notice the distance scale on each. The lens is retracted when focused at ∞, extended when focused to the MFD.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you add the source, maybe we can see the context. you can get filter threads mounted converters, like wide angle, telephoto, and macro. Though it is better to mount such things behind hte lens they do come front mounted. based on the lines we can say it is not wide angle, but tele and/or macro. a quick image google search did not come up with one that looks exactly like this one, so I cant say which model it is.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I am wondering if it could be a relay lens?

Comment: I havent seen relay lenses for DSLR sizes lenses, only CS/Cmount. But as Clark said, in this case it is just Nikon's horrible lens design that I always thought was weird :)

Comment: It's not horrible lens design at all, the internal barrel is inside at infinity and moves outwards for macro focusing.  You just don't normally see pictures of this in advertising and media and so an easy mistake.  There is no other way to get both 1:1 or 1:2 macro and have a flat field.  For what it's worth the revered 60mm 1:1 macro and other brand 90-105mm 1:1 macro lenses all do this.  It's much like how telephoto zooms extend the barrel.

Comment: Im not talking about the technical lens design. other brands also make extending lenses. Its the aesthetic design I dont like. Also their non extending lenses. nikkor lenses just look weird.

Comment: @PatrickHughes For what it is worth: many of the higher end 70-200mm f/2.8 telephoto lenses have both internal focusing and internal zoom and the barrel length doesn't change when zooming or focusing. Most shorter zoom lenses, however, do. For example my EF 70-200mm f/2.8 L IS II does not change barrel length at any combination of focal length and focus point. My EF 24-70mm f/2.8 L does.